# Fixing paths in a legacy dvi file

Tags: dvi, dvips, dvipdf

I have a legacy book written in LaTeX for which I have all sources, eps figures, and the final dvi file.

I have to produce a pdf for the book that matches the original book published in paper.

Since the book was last compiled ten years ago, I've discarded recompiling it, to avoid changing the layout due to differences in packages etc.

The obvious conversion from dvi to pdf with dvipdf did not work because the dvi has hard-coded paths for the eps figures. These paths are *absolute* paths like `/local/books/i3d/figures/eps/intro/areas.eps`.
If the paths were *relative* paths, it'd be simple to make a suitable tree with symbolic links.

I ended up editing the dvi and replacing `/local/books/i3d/` by `.local-books-i3d/`, carefully keeping the lengths the same to avoid messing up the offsets in the dvi file.

This hack worked perfectly. But I wish dvips had an option to change absolute paths to relative ones, like tar does by default.

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Isn't a `changeroot`  way easier? (apparently, you use Unix/Linux or MacOS)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer. `changeroot` would affect where `dvips` finds its own stuff, wouldn't it?

Comment: You could pretend a different root, at least. The problem is of course finding the TeX distribution or copying it over to the 'fake' root filesystem tree

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, ah, copying the TeX distribution to a fake root would work but it seems a lot of work!

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to mount the TeX tree to your change-root? Unsure, this is a rather a StackOverFlow/Unix question then

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Possible, but far more difficult than replacing strings in a binary file.

Comment: I'm glad I had the dvi file. More food for thought wrt http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130518/is-the-dvi-format-de-facto-dead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility to edit the DVI file easily is to use [dviasm](https://github.com/khaledhosny/dviasm). It creates a textual representation of the file and allows to convert this "disassembled" code back to DVI. This way you can change the paths in the text file and create a new DVI file from it afterwards.